# MySQL: Retrieving values into different columns

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select, case

Please have a look at the below code.

```
SELECT Transactions.`idTransactions`,
Transactions.`Transaction_TimeStamp`,
Transactions.`idPortfolio`,
CASE  when Transactions.`Transaction_Amount`< 0  THEN END AS "Encashments"  ELSE END AS "Additions" ,
Portfolio.Activation 
FROM Transactions 
INNER JOIN Portfolio ON Transactions.idPortfolio = Portfolio.idPortfolio 
WHERE Transactions.idPortfolio=1
ORDER BY `Transaction_TimeStamp` DESC
```

Here, if the `Transactions.Transaction_Amount` is >0, then I need to display this value in "Additions" column, else in "Encashment" column. However my code is generating errors as below.

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS "Encashments"  ELSE END AS "Additions" ,
Portfolio.Activation 
FROM Transacti' at line 4
```

How can I fix this please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want 2 different columns then use two cases

```
SELECT Transactions.`idTransactions`,
       Transactions.`Transaction_TimeStamp`,
       Transactions.`idPortfolio`,
       CASE when Transactions.`Transaction_Amount` <= 0 
            THEN  (Transaction_Amount*-1)
       END AS Encashments,
       CASE when Transactions.`Transaction_Amount` > 0 
            THEN Transaction_Amount
       END AS Additions,
       Portfolio.Activation 
FROM Transactions 
INNER JOIN Portfolio ON Transactions.idPortfolio = Portfolio.idPortfolio 
WHERE Transactions.idPortfolio=1
ORDER BY `Transaction_TimeStamp` DESC
```

Comment: I am getting errors, can you merge with the complete code pls?

Comment: Either `abs(Transaction_Amount)` or just `Transaction_Amount*-1`

Comment: Hi, There is an issue with the code. It displays encashments as additions and vice versa...

Comment: Then interchange the names

Answer (score 1):

You have no result in your case.

```
CASE  when Transactions.`Transaction_Amount`< 0  THEN something_missing_here END AS
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use your SQL as:

```
SELECT Transactions.`idTransactions`,
Transactions.`Transaction_TimeStamp`,
Transactions.`idPortfolio`,
CASE  when Transactions.`Transaction_Amount`< 0  THEN "Encashments"  ELSE "Additions" END AS Type,
Portfolio.Activation 
FROM Transactions 
INNER JOIN Portfolio ON Transactions.idPortfolio = Portfolio.idPortfolio 
WHERE Transactions.idPortfolio=1
ORDER BY `Transaction_TimeStamp` DESC
```

Your case when then syntax is wrong. You could refer [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html)